# value of array of pointers to struct changes when exiting loop

Tags: arrays, loops, pointers, array-pointer

phonebook is an array of pointers.

inside the handleMenu im allocating memory and pointing to structure where a first name is assigned to a struct that is pointed from phonebook[11].

[image]

as you can see in line 54, the name is assigned correctly and the program remembers it when exiting the handleMenu function, and i can access the details of the structure.

but after going down 1 line and ending the main while loop, the value suddenly changes.

[image]

what causes it and how to solve it? i want to remember the address to the structure but it seems that it wont save.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this first:while(option < 1 && 7 < option) this  condition will never happen!
be sure from this.
when you trying to assign array of pointer type structs it should be allocated first .